# 10k tools on meta do not have latest deletion info

Tags: bug, deleted-questions

So there's a pretty recent question I knew to be deleted. I'm including a partial screenshot for date-related purposes.

[image]

Now let's check the moderation tools (where I was hoping to find the question due to an inquiry in chat) here on meta for the last 30 days:

[image]

As can be seen the "Recently deleted" section's newest entry is from June 1st, when the question in the screenshot above has only been deleted on June 16th.

The recently deleted question are ordered by their date of deletion, but they don't include that question....

Why is that?

Comment: [Here's a link to the deleted meta questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=Delete&daterange=last30days), if anyone wants to check.